# What’s the song of Nanatsu no Taizai season 1 episode 18 remaining 2:56 minutes?

Tags: music, seven-deadly-sins

There's a song in season 1 episode 18 of *Nanatsu no Taizai and it’s when King protects Diane from Helbram attack and seconds after the captain said to Ban that Kings power was growing in incredible amount remaining 2:56 of the episode

What is the name of the song?

Comment: By "remaining 2:56", did you mean the song starts from 2:56, or around 21-minute timemark? Could you also provide the relevant scene to make it easier to identify? (you can [edit] and improve your post)

Comment: Add a link would be better...

Comment: Yes it’s when King chastiful protects Diane from Helbrams attack when Meliodas said to Ban that “Just when Gowther and Dianes power started to fade I can scenes that King was growing to incredible amount”

Comment: It’s when King protects Diane from Helbram using Chastiful

Answer (score 0):

It is called ***Rgs-7 :Zai*** by Hiroyuki Sawano. It is the 14th track from *The Seven Deadly Sins (Original Soundtrack) 2*.

[Official YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8bJWu33ZYY).